# how save changes and close without error using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in  using vba and this is my first attempt to write code.

The first workbook, `MACRO2018`, is my calculation template. Into `MACRO2018` I make a calculation and save it every time with a different name. The second workbook `UzklausulenteleGeras` is where I paste and store all summaries of these calculations.

The code which I have copies and pastes all information as I require, but `UzklausulenteleGeras` does not save and does not close. In the end I get the error

> Microsoft excel cannot access the file 'C:\C788DF00'. There are
>   several possible reasons:

I tried many workbook close and save combinations, but got the same error.

So, i'm waiting your comments and thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Uzklausa_Click()

   Workbooks.Open ("C:\UzklausulenteleGeras.xlsx")

   Workbooks("UzklausulenteleGeras").Worksheets("2018").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Select
   Selection.Copy
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
   Workbooks("UzklausulenteleGeras").Worksheets("2018").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.ClearContents

   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skaiciavimai").Range("B2:U2").Copy

   Workbooks("UzklausulenteleGeras").Worksheets("2018").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by declaring objects to represent the various workbooks. It's dangerous to rely on `ActiveWorkbook` - it may not be the workbook you think it is! Using a Workbook object you can always be sure which workbook is being acted on.

```
Private Sub Uzklausa_Click()
   Dim wbUzkl as Workbook

   Set wbUzkl = Workbooks.Open("C:\UzklausulenteleGeras.xlsx")

   wbUzkl.Worksheets("2018").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Select
   Selection.Copy
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
   wbUzkl.Worksheets("2018").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.ClearContents

   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skaiciavimai").Range("B2:U2").Copy

   wbUzkl.Worksheets("2018").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   wbUzkl.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: @davids1985 Please then activate the checkmark next to my contribution in order to mark it as "the answer". That thanks me for my time and trouble AND tells others looking for help with a similar problem that this did answer the question.